# PDF permission bits 5 and 10 (extract text and graphics)

Tags: pdf

The [PDF spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (table 22, page 61) explains permission bits 5 and 10 as follows (assuming a security handler of revision 3 or greater):

- bit 5: Copy or otherwise extract text and graphics from the document by operations other than that controlled by bit 10.
- bit 10: Extract text and graphics (in support of accessibility to users with disabilities or for other purposes).

Since the description for  bit 10 includes the phrase "... or for other purposes", I struggle to see what "operations other than that controlled by bit 10" might mean.  For a security handler of revision 3 or greater, how are these two bits used in practice?  Is bit 5 for "copy and paste" and bit 10 for accessibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That section has been updated in ISO 32000-2:

| Bit position | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Copy or otherwise extract text and graphics from the document. However, for the limited purpose of providing this content to assistive technology, a PDF reader should behave as if this bit was set to 1. NOTE For accessibility, ISO 32000-1 had this option restricted by bit 10, but that exception has been deprecated in PDF 2.0. |
| 10 | Not used. This bit was previously used to determine whether content could be extracted for the purposes of accessibility, however, that restriction has been deprecated in PDF 2.0. PDF readers shall ignore this bit and PDF writers shall always set this bit to 1 to ensure compatibility with PDF readers following earlier specifications. |

I assume the unclear formulation you wonder about led to deprecation of the distinction.